# Powershell: Apply owner to multiple files and folders per username

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-networking

We have a server that houses the My Documents folder for all our users. Some of the folder owner changed to administrator. I am trying to devise a PowerShell script that goes to each user's root my documents folder and applies the user as the owner for all the sub folders and files with in it. Is this Possible?

I have the following from a previous script that attempted to set the user as full permissions per each my document root folder:

```
$FolderPath = "E:\mydocuredir\"
$MyDocsMain = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory | ForEach-Object{

    $HomeFolders = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath $_.Name -Directory

    $Path = $HomeFolders.FullName
    $Acl = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl('Access')
    $Username = $_.Name

    $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, 'FullControl', 'ObjectInherit', 'InheritOnly', 'Allow')
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Comment: What structure is the my docs folder in, something like `E:\mydocuredir\username\?folder?`

Comment: Yes. The username folder after mydocuredir, then it's just their files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure that the share and root folder permissions for redirected folders [follow best practice](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/migreene/2008/03/24/ntfs-permissions-for-redirected-folders-or-home-directories/).

---

I would use the [NTFSSecurity](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity) PS Module ([blog on its use](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/)). This module has commands that are much easier to understand as they follow they way your would set permissions via the GUI.

```
$FolderPath = "E:\mydocuredir"

Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    Add-NTFSAccess -Path $_.FullName -Account "domain\$($_.Name)" -AccessRights FullControl -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles
}
```

To set Owner, replace the `Add-NTFSAccess` command with:

```
Set-NTFSOwner -Path $_.FullName -Account "domain\$($_.Name)"
```

Comment: I understand that this code is to assign full permissions, which seems better than my original one, but I am looking to assign the user's owner.

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: Will this instruction apply recursively to all files and sub folders and their files?

Comment: I tried the instruction, but it only changed the owner in the parent folder.

Comment: Take a look at the `Enable-NTFSInheritance` command for that.

Comment: Been trying to test it but the cmdlet isn't recognized eventhough I put the whole contents of NTFSSecurity in my c:\users\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\NTFSSecurity and with the Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity command

Comment: Ended up using this other command, which seems to be working so far `dir2 $Folder -Recurse | Set-NTFSOwner -Account 'mysuernameindomain'`